# Why is this input value not in the POST request?

Tags: html, django

On my page i got this form splitted in several divs:

```
<form id="myForm" action="{% url 'validate_question' %}" method="post">
<div id="questionanswers">
      <h2>Antworten</h2>
         {% for answer in answer_info %}
            <div id="d{{forloop.counter}}">
                <p>
                    <label><b>{{forloop.counter}}. Antwort</b></label>
                    <button id="b{{forloop.counter}}" type="button" value={{forloop.counter}}>Antwort löschen</button>
                    <input name="answer{{forloop.counter}}" class="max" type="text" value="{{ answer.3 }}"></input>
                    <input type="hidden" name="answer_id{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{answer.0}}"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="answertext_id{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{answer.2}}"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Antwort richtig?</label>
                    <input name="answercorrect{{forloop.counter}}" type="checkbox" {% if answer.1 %} checked="checked" {% endif %}></input>
                </p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
<div id="buttons">
     <input type="submit" value="Änderungen speichern." />
</div>
```

There is loop which loads all the answers to a question in this case, which the user then can edit and submit the form to save the changes. All the input in the first `<p>` gets transmitted without a problem. But for some reason the `answercorrect<id>` input of the second `<p>`isn't in my POST data after submitting the form. If I add some hidden input to the second paragraph it's there but i cant figure out what the problem with the checkbox input is.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. A checkbox input only submits a value if its checked, else there is just no value.

Comment: From this, I can't see any reason why it should be missing. What keys are in the POST QueryDict?

Comment: In a case where the box for question 1 and 2 are checked and 3 not the POST dict has those keys: `answer1, answer_id1, answertext_id1, answercorrect1, answer2, answer_id2, answertext_id2, answercorrect2, answer3, answer_id3, answertext_id3`. So answercorrect3 isnt in there when the box is unchecked.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. You could use `request.POST.get('answercorrect3', False)` to avoid a key error. Or `answercorrect3 in request.POST`